# Android dependencies

Tags: android, materialdatepicker

Somehow adding implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05' this on my dependencies make my android app failed to run

Here is the code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 28
   sourceSets {
       main {
           jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']

           assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/fonts']
       }
   }
   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "oras.liv.com.oras"
       minSdkVersion 23
       targetSdkVersion 28
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }
   buildTypes {
       debug {
           debuggable true
           jniDebuggable true
       }
       release {
           debuggable true
           jniDebuggable true
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
}

dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar'])
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
   implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
   implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0-alpha1'
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha1'
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-alpha1'
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'
   implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05'

   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


}
```

Here is the error Messsage

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:

I'm trying to use MaterialDatePicker

Comment: Looks like you have to [Migrate to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Comment: ok i will try that thanks